# In angular when i click in anywhere data will be display so can u find the error

Tags: angular

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getPosts()
      .subscribe((config: any) => {
        this.data = Object.values(config);
        this.config=this.data[0];    })}
  getPosts() {
   
    return this.http.post<any>(this.postsUrl, raw
      , { 'headers': headers });}
```

> In angular i used this method and used ngfor, and it will print data
> after any click ! help me

```
  <nb-option *ngFor="let vehicle of config" [value]="vehicle.REGIS_NO">
{{ vehicle.REGIS_NO }}
</nb-option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add detectors to detact any change after component load.

```
constructor(private cd : ChangeDetectorRef ) { }
```

Add `this.cd.markForCheck()` after `subscribe`

```
.subscribe((config: any) => {
    this.cd.markForCheck()
    this.data = Object.values(config);
```